# Team Foundation Server: References Issue

Tags: tfs, reference, namespaces, assemblies, package

I am very new to TFS and I am having trouble with references after checking out a solution and trying to build it. When I build the solution it gives me several error messages such as

"The type or namespace 'AspNet' does not exist in the 'Microsoft' namespace..."

I have tried using NuGet to manage the packages, but I still have 6 errors similar to the one above.

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Error   2   The type or namespace name 'FriendlyUrls' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Error   3   The type or namespace name 'IAppBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

(Errors 4 and 5 reference Optimization and IAppBuilder again.)

Error   6   The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I cannot figure out how to get the last few errors out, and I need to find a way to avoid having to update my solution every time I check it out of my TFS.

Comment: Is there a common Assemblies folder that you don't have latest version of?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but we figured out the issue. We were having trouble with the reference paths. I was dealing with a web site that was created by another individual. Long story short, we had to convert the web site to a web app, create a shared folder for our DLL's, reference that folder, and then add the project to Team Foundation. Once we did that everything worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were dealing with a web site and when we attempted to add this web site to our TFS it was losing our references to all DLL's (including basic web DLL's). We created a shared folder location for our DLL's, copied the DLL's into the shared folder, and then converted our website to a web application using the following tutorial:

[Converting a web site to a web application.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx)

After we converted we added the project to our TFS and it worked without any issues.